# how to pass initial state value using immutable js

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

I am using immutable js and in my reducer I am initializing the state like this:

```
     export default function reducer(state = new Map(), action = {}) {
      switch (action.type) {
        case actionType.SET_YEARS:
          return handlers.setYears(state, fromJS(action.Years));

       default:
       return state;
   }
 }
```

And then in my action I have created the action creator like this:

```
    function setYears(Years) {
     return {
       type: types.SET_YEARS,
       Years,
    };
  }
```

And in Action Handlers I am declaring the state this:

```
  export const setYears = (state, Years) => state.set('Years',Years);
```

From my component I am accessing the years like this:

```
years: state.app.get('Years') where app is the reducer name:
```

So, in the whole scenario,I am getting the years from an endpoint.I want to pass some initial value to my state so that I can get some initial values. I could do it easily without using the immutable js but not sure how to set the initial values in immutable state property.Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks in Advance.

reducer:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';
import * as handlers from './actionHandlers';
import * as actionType from './actionTypes';

const initialState = new Map({
  Years: [{ year: 2017 }, { year: 2016 }],
});
export default function reducer(state = new Map(), action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case actionType.SET_YEARS:
      return handlers.setYears(state, fromJS(action.Years));

    default:
      return state;
  }
```

}
combineReducer:

```
  const reducer = combineReducers({
    app: appReducer,
  });
```

sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-williams-hnrg1?file=/src/YearsView.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to pass an object to the initial state.

you can do

```
const initialState = Map({Years:1});
```

I'll update the full code as per the comments for the answer provided

```
//Actions.js
export const updateYears = Years => {
    return {
        type: 'UpdateYears',
         Years
    };
};
```

//Reducer.js combine reducer is placed in same file as well

```
const setYears = (state, Years) => state.set('Years', Years);
const initialState = new Map({
    Years: [{ year: 2017 }, { year: 2016 }],
});
const commonReducer = (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
    switch (action.type) {

        case 'UpdateYears':
            return setYears(state, [...state.get('Years'),fromJS(action.Years)]);

        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default combineReducers({
    common: commonReducer
});

//Years View
const YearsView = props => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(props.years));
        setTimeout(()=>{
            props.dateActions.updateYears([{ years: 333 }]);
        },2000);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {
                JSON.stringify(props.years)
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default connect(state => ({
    years: state.common.get('Years')
}), dispatch => {
    return {
        dateActions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    }
})(YearsView);
```

When years view is mounted the useeffect will fire the action after 2 seconds

```
const YearsView = props => {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(props.years));
        setTimeout(()=>{
            props.dateActions.updateYears([{ years: 333 }]);
        },2000);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            {
                JSON.stringify(props.years)
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default connect(state => ({
    years: state.common.get('Years')
}), dispatch => {
    return {
        dateActions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
    }
})(YearsView);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried that already but then in the component when I am trying to access the state,I am getting an error that state.get is not function something like that

Comment: try using state.app.getIn('Years')

Comment: that did work but now the problem is it only display the default initial state values and can't display the values from the endpoint although the endpoint values are stored in redux state...

Comment: can you update your question with the combine reducer?

Comment: is your componentdidupdate firing once the store is updated ?

Comment: I am using useEffect and yes it just fire only once when the component renders

Comment: i tried the code you provided with a useeffect hook to call the update and it works fine, still dont see what i'm missing

Comment: still didn't try that but will try it soon and let you know,,,

Comment: So, I have tried your code, it actually display the new year passed using the useEffect Hook and then the initial state becomes disappeared. Is it possible to declares initial years in the state and then pass the year from useEffect(in my case from an API) and then in the component list all the years from the state

Comment: So you want to add the year coming from the API to the array in the state is it ?

Comment: here is the demo link it only displays the year passed with the useEffect..https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-williams-hnrg1?file=/src/YearsView.js

Comment: yes,I want to add the year coming from the API to the state and also need to be able to declare some initial years from state,

Comment: Only change is this       return setYears(state, [...state.get('Years'),fromJS(action.Years)]); in the reducer, check the answer :)

Comment: thanks for the answers it's work fine but now that when I try to map and display year to individual component it throws an error.. year.get() is not a function, can be checked from the sandbox link

Comment: should be         <Year key={year.year} year={year.year} />  :)

Comment: does that re structure the immutable js format? at least the place I am trying to use that approach is deeply nested component consists of immutable js structure. although that .notation fixed my earlier issue

Comment: It is, you get the immutable object at connect and use the normal js object in the component